# Node: How to handle the POST request without using a framework

Tags: javascript, node.js

So in all my research, I was not able to find any topic related to GET and POST in "Vanilla Node", Everyone was recommending to use Express.

But I wanted to learn Node.js and its complete functionality before attempting Express.

**For Example**:

Let's say I have an HTML file that contains a Signup form.
On Submit how will I send the data to the database with "Vanilla Node"?

Thank you

Comment: One word: `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: `fetch()` is the easy way...

Comment: @dandavis Yes I will check it out , Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http core-module in Node.js. You can distinguish endpoints using `request.path` and handle it accordingly. For more ideas Refer [HTTP module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    // For all POST REQUESTS
  } else {
  }
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: But how will I get the values of the input?  Should i use document,getElementById?

Comment: @dandavis How to handle the POST request without using a framework? This means creation of REST API and its handler right?

Comment: @ThanveerShah What do you mean? Do you want to call a REST API or create a REST API?

Comment: No, So I have a simple Signup form, I just want to store the data to the database onsubmit.

Comment: yes, but the question seems to be about going from html to node, not node to node...

Comment: @dandavis I am confused. AFAIU he wants server side setup code without any framework and not making HTTP requests .

Comment: @ThanveerShah For that you would need a server application setup using node.js or its frameworks like ExpressJS and you need to make a REST API call using methods in the HTML file specified by dandavis and others.

Comment: So basically it's not possible with Vanilla Node is what you are saying?

Comment: @ThanveerShah Vanilla Node.js means Node.js without using any frameworks like Express. For your requirment you need to create  a server side application using node.js and create corresponding API endpoints and call them using fetch() in HTML file.